# SQL query: where any dump value is greater than 96

Tags: sql, oracle

I recently encountered a couple of values that are causing exceptions in our application. A look into the db reveiled that we may have imported erroneous data (which must not be modified!). We now found that the cause of this error lies in unicode problems.

To find all relevant error records, I dumped the values I have already identified (manually) and could see, that the problematic vaules lie above the value 96, an example below:

```
Typ=96 Len=10: 83,85,49,89,36,73,219,190,159,87
```

Whereas 219,190,159 are problematic. This can be obtained through `select dump(col) from table`, however I would like to further only select records where one of the values in the dump exceed 99 -pretty much like (***pseudo code***) `length(string(value)) for value in dump_record > 96`  Is there any way to do this? Thanks folks.

Comment: This already is the dump. What I would need is some sort of subquery, that takes only records where a value > 96 is in that dump() result. 
Adapted, its oracle, mysql tag was a mistake, sorry.

Comment: I'd cut the header from `DUMP(value)` then search the string by regular expression for `\d{3}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question. See if it helps; follow comments within code:

```
SQL> with
  2  data (col) as
  3     -- sample data:
  4     -- 123LITTlefOOT results in Typ=96 Len=13: 49,50,51,76,73,84,84,108,101,102,79,79,84
  5     -- where marked values are > 96                                 --- --- ---
  6     --
  7     -- BIG997FOOT    results in Typ=96 Len=10: 66,73,71,57,57,55,70,79,79,84 which is OK
  8    (select '123LITTlefOOT' from dual union all
  9     select 'BIG997FOOT'    from dual
 10    ),
 11  test as
 12    -- DUMP of sample data
 13    (select col,
 14            dump(col) dmp
 15     from data
 16    ),
 17  -- remove TYP=XX Len=yy
 18  test2 as
 19    (select col,
 20            dmp,
 21            trim(substr(dmp, instr(dmp, ':') + 1)) tdmp
 22     from test
 23    ),
 24  -- split TDMP into rows
 25  trows as
 26    (select col,
 27            dmp,
 28            regexp_substr(tdmp, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) str
 29     from test2 cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 30                                               connect by level <= regexp_count(tdmp, ',') + 1
 31                                              ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 32    )
 33  select distinct col, dmp
 34  from trows
 35  where to_number(str) > 96;

COL           DMP
------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
123LITTlefOOT Typ=1 Len=13: 49,50,51,76,73,84,84,108,101,102,79,79,84

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks,it took me some time to work with this, however I could not manage to "find" other records I was not aware of before.

Comment: You're welcome; I saw you posted the solution. Much simpler than mine!

Answer (score 0):

Regex totally did it, I used the simple below solution:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE regexp_like(dump(t.error_col), '\d{3}');
```

Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: Great! I'm glad you did it. Thank you for letting us know.

Comment: This would find a string where `len=100`. If you use `'[, ]\d{3}'` as the regular expression then it would not match on the `len=` term and just match on the later byte values.

Comment: That's right, but I can be sure, that len=XX never exceeds double digit. Great hint though, cheers.